# Compute $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin(x)\ln(1-x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arcsin(x)\ln(1-x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Wich direction should I take to compute , with computer I found

$$-\pi^3/8$$

Comment: Thank you for suggestion to compute this integral.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes haha. Deleted the comment, because I realized that.

Comment: I guess $x=\cos u$ would be a better substitution  because we can write $\arcsin $ in terms of $\arccos$ also the $\ln$ part would breakdown in a better way and just the derivative of $\arccos$ with an extra minus sign is present in the integrand

Comment: It is ok I found the way to compute it, thank's.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{2}[(Arc sin x)^2]'=\frac{Arc sinx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $